# Query Plan for Excel SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

Does Excel (2016) create a SQL Query plan when connecting to an existing (SQL) connection from within Excel?  Are there any disadvantages of using Excel to access database versus using a stored procedure in SQL Server?

Comment: Your second question is too broad, really. The answer is that it depends on what you want to do with your data. Sometimes Excel is probably great. Sometimes it's entirely the wrong tool for the job. For instance, if you want to see your execution plan.

Comment: You can also execute and retrieve data via a stored procedure from Excel. Meaning you can do the optimization on the SQL Server side.

Comment: Does excel create or cause SQL Server to create an execution plan? By using Excel to retrieve data using it’s built-in data connections process, is there any drag on the performance of the database. I’m being told that every time the query runs from Excel SQL Server has to create a new plan. They’re suggesting using a stored procedure instead. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

No, Excel does not create query plans.  It simply sends a query to SQL Server, and the database engine creates the execution plan.